# Implementing AES-GCM with 128-bit blocks and 256-bit key

Tags: c#, encryption, rijndaelmanaged, aes-gcm

I do not usually work with encryption but I need to use **AES-GCM** algorythm in C# with *128-bit blocks* and *256-bit key*.

I already read many articles about it but I can't find a valid solution.

Maybe:

https://github.com/lukemerrett/Bouncy-Castle-AES-GCM-Encryption  / **BouncyCastle**

or

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnfa/2009/03/17/authenticated-symmetric-encryption-in-net/

Can be valid solutions? Is there something already present in the Framework?

Is it possible to implement the same solution in *ASP.NET 2.0*? (I found: https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: AES with a blocksize of 256 bits doesn't exist.  Rijndael does?  Is that what you mean?  Have a look at BouncyCastle.  It's on NuGet.

Comment: You are right. I have investigated this problem and edited my post.

Comment: I suggest you read the C# example in [this repository](https://github.com/luke-park/SecureCompatibleEncryptionExamples).  There are examples for 9 other languages as well, if that helps.

Comment: It's very similar to link I posted.... Can you explain the differences? In your solution I have to change some parameters... And in .Net 2.0?

Comment: The example I posted is compatible across standard implementations (hence the number of languages it is translated into).  The link you posted uses a non-standard nonce size that makes it difficult to use in other languages.  Other than that, pretty similar.  At the end of the day, if you aren't any good at cryptography, you probably shouldn't be using it!  Hire someone that knows what they are doing.

Comment: Are you referring to 128? It must be 12. So i need to edit your sample only for key size (256)

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: And in Net 2.0? I can write something similar? BouncyCastle is for > 3.5.

Comment: Well, no, because all that code uses methods from BouncyCastle...

Comment: In your opinion, in .Net 2.0 can I use existing `RijndaelManaged`?

Comment: No, GCM is not supported in .NET 2.0

Comment: Thanks. I'm checking your code in c#. Key size has not to be 256 -as told before - but 32!

Comment: You're confusing bits and bytes.